# Javascript calculate 2 states

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have some struggles with Javascript. I'm trying to calculate simple Vue states, calculating price of item, quantity and total price, so it looks like that in 2 functions.

```
calculatePCSPrice: function (index) {
    this.products[index].price_pcs = this.products[index].full_price / this.products[index].qty;
},

calculateTotalPrice: function (index) {
    this.products[index].full_price = this.products[index].price_pcs * this.products[index].qty;
},
```

I did it like this because I don't know how to do it in one function, tried like this:

```
calculatePrice: function (index) {
    this.calculatePCSPrice(index);
    this.calculateTotalPrice(index);
},
```

But it's changing only pcs price.
Any ideas how to fix that, and return values with function toFixed(2)?

Answer (score 3):

Since your code snippets are really small i had to imagine the environment of that functions. But what i guessed works as expected - i don't know why it's not working for you.

**Working example:**

```js
var shop = {
    products: [
        {
            price_pcs: 0,
            full_price: 19,
            qty: 5
        },
        {
            price_pcs: 0,
            full_price: 25,
            qty: 7
        }
    ],
    calculatePCSPrice: function(index) {
        this.products[index].price_pcs = (this.products[index].full_price / this.products[index].qty).toFixed(2);
    },

    calculateTotalPrice: function(index) {
        this.products[index].full_price = (this.products[index].price_pcs * this.products[index].qty).toFixed(2);
    },
    calculatePrice: function(index) {
        this.calculatePCSPrice(index);
        this.calculateTotalPrice(index);
    }
};

shop.calculatePrice(0);
shop.calculatePrice(1);
console.log(shop.products);
```

Comment: Because I'm changing this states, I use keyup on input. And when I'm changing both it's not working.

Comment: Sorry, i have no clou what that means. Could you please be more detailed? (at best in the question)